# Correctly indent multiline lists, maps, tuples and function heads in Erlang with Vim

Tags: vim, erlang, indentation

I have been struggling with indentation in Erlang and Vim for quite some time. I tried [vimerl](https://github.com/oscarh/vimerl) and [vim-erlang-runtime](https://github.com/vim-erlang/vim-erlang-runtime), but I always end up with the same strange indentation for multiline lists, tuples, maps and function heads which leads me to think that there might be some additional settings that I am missing.

Here is a short example of what the auto indentation gives me:

```erlang
  TestList = [
              a,
              b
             ],

  TestTuple = {
    a,
    b
   },

  TestMap = #{
              a => 0,
              b => 1
             },

  {ok, _} = mymodule:myfunc(
              a,
              b
             ),
```

I would like to get something closer to what I would automatically get in other languages:

```erlang
  TestList = [
    a,
    b
  ],

  TestTuple = {
    a,
    b
  },

  TestMap = #{
    a => 0,
    b => 1
  },

  {ok, _} = mymodule:myfunc(
    a,
    b
  ),
```

What would be the simplest way to achieve this?